# Batch convert dae to scn

Tags: scenekit, arkit

Is there a way to batch convert Collada dae files to Scenekit scn files?

My project uses approx 50 models created in sketchup that are updated regularly, these are exported to DAE but also need to be converted to SCN files for usage in xCode. I know it can be done manually via xCode and "Convert to SceneKit scene file format (scn)" but this take to much manual labour.

Answer (score 3):

Based on https://the-nerd.be/2014/11/07/dynamically-load-collada-files-in-scenekit-at-runtime/ I figured out that the scntool is able to convert it via the command line and write the following script:

```
find ./dae -name "*.dae" | while read f ; do 
inputfilename=$(basename $f)
echo $inputfilename
./scntool --convert $f --format scn --output ./scn/$inputfilename
done
for file in ./scn/*.dae; do
    mv "$file" "./scn/$(basename "$file" .dae).scn"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

@HixField has a good shell script for invoking `scntool`. Another way to do that is to leverage Xcode's build system, which does the same thing for any `.dae` files you put in a project's `scnassets` folder. Even if you're not bundling those files in your app, you can create a dummy Xcode target or project that contains all the assets you want to convert, and it'll convert them all whenever you build the target. (Which you could then integrate into a CI system or other automation.)

Comment: Also I agree with you about that in fact I was doing exactly same for all my projects  but I was having problem when converting large Collada (DAE) files , and I thought its my old MacBook so I risk it and get a very latest Mac M1 which suppose to do it for me but still Xcode stuck when I loaded the DAE and then I made my searches and trials till I found that the only way to do it for large files is by using scntool. So yes I agree with you for all DAE files under 200mb But for my project it was 214mb and I really could not do it without the scntool command .

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Hixfield About everything except you need to add one more option to the scntool to get your materials correctly without need to re add all manually

```
scntool --convert INPUT.dae --format scn --output OUT.scn --asset-catalog-path .
```

The dot at the end of the command line is very important it means you will set resources to same location

If you don’t set the —asset-catalog-path . You will have no materials